# I wish to store large amounts of data client side in Chrome, what are my options?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm working on client-side only thing that crunches some numbers and displays them in  graphs.

I pull the data from a server. To start with I saved the data to localStorage every 24 hours, this worked for a while but now the data-set is to large to fit in localStorage. Firefox allows you to remove the size-limit on localStorage, but Chrome doesn't have any setting like that. I would prefer working in Chrome.

Chrome supports the `requestFileSystem` API, that allows you to create and save files, but other browsers have decided to not support it and not very well documented/widely used. Ideally I would prefer something that chrome is more committed to, so they don't drop support for it all of a sudden.

This application is only for me, so some extensions, advanced settings is fine, also some way to set the cahcing for the data-file i'm importing, client side would work.

Comment: Why would you want to store such large amounts of data in Chrome?  Seems odd to me - wouldn't a database make more sense?  Chrome isn't really designed to be a database/document store...or at least I didn't think so anyway.

Comment: how are you pulling from the server? is this manual?

Comment: @atmd JSON onpageload if it's more than 24hrs since last time.

Comment: @MatRichardson, i'm primarily a frontend developer and a really crappy sys-admin ;) I'm happy with my current setup except that the server takes ~16 secounds to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IndexedDB. Here are some comparisons b/w localstorage & IndexedDB

### localstorage

- small data
- synchronous
- key-value pair

### IndexedDB

- large data
- asynchronous
- provides indexes
- can run query
- supports transactions & simple data types
- stores data in form of objects
- Ex: To do lists(keep.google.com)

Answer (score -1):

You have the local storage API: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

The File API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFile

Mozilla also simplified the local storage API with the local forage API: http://mozilla.github.io/localForage/

These are just some options.

Comment: op has said "now the data-set is to large to fit in localStorage"

Comment: Maybe the file API could be used... Can i Specify the place (and name) where the file should be saved?

Comment: Kinda of, yes, but only in the user interface. For security reasons the JavaScript won't know where the file is on disk. I found some use with this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/